# Appium-Eclipse-Maven: No tests to run

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, automated-tests, appium

I'm trying to run a very simple Appium-Test with eclipse and maven. But I get alwayse "No tests to run"-Message.

**This is my test-file:**

```
package MyPackage;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class AdviqoAppiumTest {

static AndroidDriver ad;

@Before
public  AppiumDriver setUp() {
//set up appium
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.3.6");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "htc-htc_one-FA396W907439");
capabilities.setCapability("udid", "192.168.168.88");
capabilities.setCapability("app",    "/Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/myProject/project/build/outputs/apk/App-colored-beta.apk");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.me.myProject.project");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.me.myProject.project.ui.start.SplashScreen");

URL url=null;
try
{
    url = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub/status");
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ad = new AndroidDriver(url,capabilities);
return ad;

}
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception{
ad.quit();
}

@Test
public static void test(){

assertEquals(ad.currentActivity() ,".ui.start.SplashScreen");
ad.findElement(By.id("welcome_ok_btn")).click();
ad.closeApp();
}   
}
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>AppiumTest</groupId>
<artifactId>AppiumTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>AppiumTest</name>
<prerequisites>
   <maven>2.2.1</maven>
 </prerequisites>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.3</version>
    </plugin>
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

**In terminal:** 
mvn -Dtest=MyPackage.AdviqoAppiumTest test

**After few minutes in terminal:**
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------  --------
    [INFO] Building AppiumTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @  AppiumTest ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/me/Documents/workspace/AppiumTest/src/test/java/src/main/resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:compile (default-compile) @  AppiumTest ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ AppiumTest ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/me/Documents/workspace/AppiumTest/src/test/java/src/test/resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:testCompile (default-testCompile)   @AppiumTest ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.3:test (default-test) @ AppiumTest ---
    [INFO] No tests to run.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.918s
    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 25 15:07:09 CET 2015
    [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/156M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

**On http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub/status:**
{"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"edcb7784cb3de1d6a3ca041f86cba8bc8b1f14f5"}}}

**If you need something else, just ask.
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: First your path to your files looks wrong `ace/AppiumTest/src/test/java/src/test/resources` should be `src/test/java` + package Name (In your case MyPackage). Furthermore you should use up-to-date versions of the plugins and not such ancient versions. Please check: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/. Use to execute your test `mvn clean test` nothing more.

Comment: Do I have to create a Maven-Project or normal Java-Project under Eclipse?

Comment: And if I just run mvm clean install how I can see the test results? Because in terminal there is just a Build Successful massage with No test to run-massage.

Comment: There should be an output like: `Tests run: ... errors: ... failed` etc. otherwise something is wrong.

Comment: Do you have m2e-android installed?